# can we refresh page automatically in flutter?

Tags: dart, flutter

how to make data to load after sometime when it is getting updated in server. How to do auto refresh entire page after some particular interval

Comment: Use a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder`

Comment: inside future builder only i am showing list view but still when i am navigating back from next page data is not updating because api is not getting called..

Comment: what i need is to load all api's in page automatically for regular intervals

Comment: Not sure what that means exactly, but I think a `StreamBuilder` is the right thing for repeated events.

Comment: okay Thanks will try, but for those fields which are not in list view how to update them??

Comment: Your question doesn't contain any information about "those fields which are not in list view" ;-)

Comment: i mean variable values in database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `StreamBuilder` and your `stream` argument would be something like:

```
stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child(
      "profiles").onValue
```

`onValue` will fetch the new snapshot whenever your API updates.